# Why does the if work only sometimes?

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I have this code in my project for checking the controller and the action in my .cshtml-file:

```
@if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] == "Home" && ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] == "Index")
{
    //Some html
}
```

When I open the page at the root (http://localhost/), it shows the given html. But when I open it with the full link (http://localhost/Home/Index) it's not showing up.

When put the variables in the html of the webpage, they are exactly the same.

Why isn't this working then?

Comment: Debugging is probably the easiest way to figure out that... Set breakpoint and check the values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

Use `.Equals("")` instead of `==`.

## Explanation

`ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]` is of type `object`. If you want to check the equality of the content, you first need to resolve the underlying type as `String`. If you use `==`, then C# doesn't resolve the underlying type before doing the comparison. When you use `Equals()`, C# does resolve the underlying type first. Here's why C# needs to know the underlying type.

When you use the `==` operator, and one of the operands is an `object`, the check is for reference equality. In your question, it doesn't matter that underlying type is `String`, because C# doesn't check the underlying type. If it did check the underlying type, then the `==` would work, but it doesn't. It just checks whether the two references are the same. [See MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx).

If you really want to use `==`, then you can tell C# explicitly to use a `string` comparison.

- `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()`
- `(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string)`
- `((string)ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"])`

It's probably best just to use the `Equals(string)` method. C# will figure out on its own that you're working with a `String`. In other words, it does matter that the underlying type is a `String`, because C# resolves the underlying type before calling any method on an `object`. And the comparison will be for content not reference equality, because the underlying type is `String`. [See MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

## Fiddle

Here is [a Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9t5BFm) for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
        @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]

        @if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].Equals("Home") 
             && ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].Equals("Index"))
        {
            <p>True</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>False</p>
        }

        @if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] == "Home" 
             && ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] == "Index")
        {
            <p>True</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>False</p>
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest revert it like this, in case of null

```
@if ("Home".Equals(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]) && "Index".Equals(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]))
{
    //Some html
}
```